# Maven Project Import

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I imported maven project into my eclipse from external resource. But when i try to create my own class in that project under a package i see

" Source folder is not on the Java build class path."

When i tried to run java classes of that project i see a "Launch Error- Editor does not contain a main type"

Please provide the steps to configure maven project from external source into our eclipse and how to configure build path and other dependencies as i am a newbie to Maven.

Comment: How exactly did you import?

Comment: Does the project have a class with `public static void main`?

Answer (score 0):

Import the existing maven project using, *File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven Projects*

After import, do maven clean package to check it doesn't have any build errors.

Then try adding your own class and see if it works and of course to run the java class alone you need to have the main method in it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I import a project and it's a maven project I have to right click on the project, choose Configure and then choose Convert to Maven Faceted Project (or something like that) - I cannot recall exactly.